Connect shapes into one
I buffered these shapes by 20m and debuffered by 20m which is the exact measurement I need so I can't de/buffer anymore.
Is there a way to connect the shapes by a thin rectangle or a line?


Are multipolygons not good for you? Do you really need these polygons to be physically connected or do you just want them to share the same attributes?

Are each pair one multipolygon or two single part polygons? If they are two polygons, do they share some common attribute/id?

@Bera Yes, they a multipolygon, selecting one will select both as they have common attributes. I need them to be '1' shape, something like the green lines would be ideal.

Can't you buffer/debuffer by a larger distance so that groups which are further away remain connected?

@Kasper I have tested this and when debuffering the gap between gets too thin and splits the shape in half, even when I debuff by a few metres than what I buffered.

Depending on how many polygons you want to join this way, you could just digitize thin polygons between the larger ones to be joined, then merge the results.


Multipart to Singleparts to break the multipart into singlepart polygons. Name the output Single parts
Create a Virtual Layer using the query:

select a.id, st_buffer(shortestline(a.geometry, b.geometry), 2) as geometry
from "Single parts" a
join "Single parts" b
on a.id=b.id
where not Equals(a.geometry, b.geometry)

The query join singleparts if they share the same id, but the geometries are different.
Then creates a shortest line between them and buffer it to create a polygon.
Then you can merge this layer with your start layer and dissolve if you want to.

